# How can I fix this automake and autoconf missing issue?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, automake, autoconf

I am trying to install avro-keyboard on Kali Linux but I am getting this error message on folowing this step from the tutorials:

```
root@al-ajal:~# apt-get install git ibus libibus-1.0-dev automake autoconf gjs gir1.2-ibus-1.0 ibus-1.0

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libibus-1.0-5' for regex 'ibus-1.0'
Note, selecting 'gir1.2-ibus-1.0' for regex 'ibus-1.0'
Package autoconf is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package automake is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package ibus
E: Unable to locate package libibus-1.0-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libibus-1.0-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libibus-1.0-dev'
E: Package 'automake' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'autoconf' has no installation candidate
```

What's wrong? I did not find any discussion regarding what to do if autoconf or automake is missing in the tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

in the main repo of kali rolling autoconf and automake-1.15 are available first you should update the repo

Comment: Perhaps you need to include some step-by-step instructions to make your answer understandable for a wider audience ...

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-avro
```

You have to install avro using the above command